How to access the fragments button from hosting activity in android?
I have few fragments hosted by an acticity, i want to access specific fragments' button on the fragment view from the hosting activity
from the fragment i can access activitie's button like this
btnSubmit = (MaterialButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);

i want to do the inverse of this, is there any method to do this?

What exactly are you trying to do with the button?

@tyczj I want to disable it manually from a method in my activity

Instead of "accessing the fragment buttons", you should "observe shared state". Have a ViewModel scoped to the Activity that contains the state of the button. You can access this VM in the Activity to set the state (disabled) and you can access this VM in any fragment that cares to observe the state. See: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#host-activity

@dominicoder Thank you, I hope this will work in my scenario

The proper way to do something with the fragment from the activity would be as follows
Fragment
class MyFragment: Fragment(){

    var button: Button? = null

    override fun onCreateView(){
        ...
        button = view.findViewById(..)
    }

    fun disable(){
        button.enabled = false
    }
}

Activity
using the fragment manager find the fragment by its id (or other means) and cast it as your fragment
then call the method of that fragment (see MyFragment above) to disable the button
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity(){

    fun disableFragmentButton(){
        val fragmentId = adapter.getItemId(positionOfYourFragmentInTheAdapter)
        if(fragmentId > -1){
            (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(fragmentId) as MyFragment).disable()
        }
    }
}

You should always avoid directly accessing UI components of the fragment from the activity

How can i find the id of the fragment, I am creating the fragment with FragmentStateAdapter -> createFragment

oh you are using a viewpager or something?

yeah, I am using viewpager2 with FragmentStateAdapter

thats a little trickier because you have to get it from the adapter with getItemId with gives you the fragment id. You might have to do some additional checks to make sure an id is returnd if the fragment does not exist in the adapter

that's confusing, do you have a clear tutorial or blog or stack question on this?
